# Stateful DoFn with Side Input - DirectRunner issue?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a stateful DoFn with a `beam.pvalue.AsSingleton` side input. When I was trying to write a test for this DoFn, I've noticed a strange behavior: Sometimes the execution fails with an `ValueError` stating that the stateful DoFn requires a key-value pair as input, i.e.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/playground/backend/executable_files/afa71397-d19b-4088-8d4b-85d16735631e/afa71397-d19b-4088-8d4b-85d16735631e.py", line 38, in <module>
    dot = pipeline_graph.PipelineGraph(pipeline).get_dot()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/interactive/display/pipeline_graph.py", line 78, in __init__
    pipeline, pipeline._options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/interactive/pipeline_instrument.py", line 72, in __init__
    pipeline.to_runner_api(), pipeline.runner, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 913, in to_runner_api
    root_transform_id = context.transforms.get_id(self._root_transform())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/pipeline_context.py", line 104, in get_id
    self._id_to_proto[id] = obj.to_runner_api(self._pipeline_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 1304, in to_runner_api
    for part in self.parts
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 1304, in <listcomp>
    for part in self.parts
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/pipeline_context.py", line 104, in get_id
    self._id_to_proto[id] = obj.to_runner_api(self._pipeline_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 1291, in to_runner_api
    transform_spec = transform_to_runner_api(self.transform, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 1286, in transform_to_runner_api
    named_inputs=self.named_inputs())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 742, in to_runner_api
    urn, typed_param = self.to_runner_api_parameter(context, **extra_kwargs)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1429, in to_runner_api_parameter
    extra_kwargs.get('named_inputs', None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1393, in _get_key_and_window_coder
    'key-value pairs.' % self)
ValueError: Input elements to the transform <ParDo(PTransform) label=[ParDo(StatefulWithSideInput)] side_inputs=[AsSingleton(PCollection[side/Map(decode).None])]> with stateful DoFn must be key-value pairs.
```

which is quite confusing, since I clearly provide a key-value input - only my side input has no key-value pair. The actual logic within the DoFn seems to be irrelevant, since this MWE causes the same issue

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.transforms.userstate import ReadModifyWriteStateSpec
from apache_beam.coders import StrUtf8Coder

class StatefulWithSideInput(beam.DoFn):
  MYSTATE = ReadModifyWriteStateSpec('my_state', StrUtf8Coder())
  def process(self,
              element=beam.DoFn.ElementParam,
              side=beam.DoFn.SideInputParam,
              state=beam.DoFn.StateParam(MYSTATE)):
    yield element[1]
    
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  side_input = (
    pipeline
    | "side" >> beam.Create(['test'])
  )
  main = (
    pipeline
    | "main" >> beam.Create([('1', 2)])
  )

  (
    main
    | beam.ParDo(StatefulWithSideInput(), beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(side_input))
    | beam.Map(print)
  )
```

Most of the time the code works without any errors and returns the expected result `2`, but sporadically I get the `ValueError`. My actual DoFn is more complex (e.g., uses the side input and the state variable) and runs perfectly fine on Dataflow (no errors there). The first time I've encountered this issue is when I was trying to write a test for this DoFn.

Is this a DirectRunner issue/bug? Do I do something wrong when providing input for `StatefulWithSideInput`? But then again, why it is most of the time working?

Comment: Hello, could you solve this? I'm stucked right now with the same problem...

Comment: Nope, this issue still persists. I believe I need to open a github issue and see if it is a DirectRunner bug

Comment: @Mikel I've found a solution to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally come up with a solution. While it might not fix the underlying issue (if there is one with the DirectRunner), at least the unit tests can be run consistently without any weird errors.

You need to tell `Beam` the output type (depending on your specific case) of your side input, i.e.

```
  side_input = (
    pipeline
    | "side" >> beam.Create(['test']).with_output_types('str')
  )
```

See here the full example, runable in [apache beam play](https://play.beam.apache.org/?sdk=python&shared=OpsRiNh_GPr)

Comment: Thanks! Finally I used a different approach using a Singleton pattern instead of a statefull side input as it didn't fit my use case.